# How to take a "empty string" as input in C++?

Tags: string, input

I am facing a problem when i am going to form a string with "enter" only . If someone just press "enter " as input , it will be a input and string size will be Zero . In c++ , using "cin" , how can I do that ?

Comment: what do you mean with "counting a string"???

Comment: Counting a string means recognised  it as string .